# Move file at system restart

Tags: macos, cocoa, objective-c++

I want to copy a file at system restart on MAC OS X.

On windows I am using MoveFileEx API for that.

Please tell me what is the way of doing that in MAC.

Thanks,
Vaibhav D. Gade.

Answer (score 0):

You want [TN2228: Running At Login](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2228/). Besides describing one solution, it also gives summary descriptions of the other solutions and when each one is (and isn't) appropriate.